# jquery submit form with select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to perform a submit with AJAX and select list. I made a simple alert but nothing. Did I misss something ?
This is my html:

```
            <form id='bill_action' action='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='bill_id' value='".$v1['id']."'>
            <select name='action' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                <option value='test1'>test1</option>
                <option value='test2'>test2</option>
            </select>

            </form>
```

my JS:

```
$("#bill_action").submit(function() {
    alert('hello world'); //for test
    $.ajax({ //make ajax request to bill_action.php
        url: "bill_action.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
        data: bill_id
    }).done(function(data){ 
//on Ajax success
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<form id='bill_action' action='post'>
 <input type='hidden' name='bill_id' value='".$v1['id']."'>
 <select name='action' onchange='myfunction'>
     <option value='test1'>test1</option>
     <option value='test2'>test2</option>
 </select>

 </form>


function myfunction() {
    alert('hello world'); //for test
    $.ajax({ //make ajax request to bill_action.php
        url: "bill_action.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
        data: bill_id
    }).done(function(data){ 
        //on Ajax success
    })
}
```

Comment: Your data value is undefined, you might meant `data: $('[name=bill_id]').val()`

Comment: try this :  data: $('[name="bill_id"]').val()

Comment: No, that wasn't my point, you have a variable named `bill_id` and it is undefined, you are not posting any json